# Материалы для изучения информационной безопасности

Tags: алгоритм

Интересуюсь информационной безопасностью и технологиями.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, ЛЮБОЙ материал (ТЕКСТ, ВИДЕО, АУДИО) для саморазвития и понимания

- **Основ** криптографии, интернет безопасности (всякие протоколы шифроввания, термины на подобии пинг и т.д), информационной безопасности
- Что-нибудь про все самые возможные и известные алгоритмы (для общего развития), материал про машинное обучение , и еще что нибудь на подобии Машины Тьюринга, цикла Дейкстры и т.д. и *выносящеее мозг* сложностью пониманияя
- самое главное - это какой нибудь **базис** элементарных(что должен знать любой программист) алгоритмов, понятий , терминов.

P.S Пока еще учусь в школе в старших классах и можно что нибудь из институтской программы. Желательно *МНОГО* материала. Можно предлагать книги, учебники (вообще шикарно), лекции. Те, кто читает журнал "Хакер" - поймут о каком БАЗИСЕ я говорю (а то я задолбался лазить по википедии для понимания их статей).

Курсы **ITVDN** не предлагать, я и так по ним учусь. Спасибо!

Comment: Ваш топик - странный предмет. Изучать хотите, а искать - нет.

Comment: Материалы по ИБ, да еще и выносящие мозг? Ну теория чисел в самый раз будет...

Comment: Думаю для начала вам стоит начать с "Криптономикон"  Нил Стивенсон ))) Да и вообще Стивенсон )))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По опыту могу рекомендовать для начала замутить какую-нибудь случайную побитовую функцию над числами сначала на машинке Тьюринга, потом на [машине Поста](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0) и на десерт в [нормальном алгоритме Маркова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC). Эмуляторы для этого можно найти в сети, [даже онлайн](http://cmcmsu.no-ip.info/1course/alg.schema.nam.htm), или смастерить самому, если хватит желания. Для любителей математики будет приятным занятием перевод двоичных выражений из одного [базиса (т.е. набора операций)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B) в другой. Ну а если это не показалось особо сложным, предлагаю ощутить прелести [функционального программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), на том же [Лиспе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF).

После дискретной математики полезно кодить всяческие алгоритмы сортировки на плюсах ([вставками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), [пирамидальная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), [слиянием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC), [быстрая](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)), разные структуры данных ([одно- и двухсвязные списки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA), стеки, очереди...). Полезно научиться понимать и находить [вычислительную сложность алгоритмов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). Ах, да, [динамическое программирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и [задача о рюкзаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5) к месту также.

Конечно, по ходу дела нужно разобраться с [динамическим выделением памяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8) и ссылками, указателями, если этого не было сделано раньше. Немножко стоит поиграться с [адресной арифметикой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)#.D0.90.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0), понять представление разных типов (особенно числа с плавающей точкой) в компьютере, вручную переводить числа в [обратном](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) и [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0))

Далее стоит перейти к ООП. В начале нужно здесь понять основы: [шаблоны](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_C%2B%2B), [интерфейсы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), [наследование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), [агрегация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.90.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F), [композиция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F).

Вот теперь, после всех этих основ, можно будет по-настоящему углубиться в интересующую отрасль: дискретную математику и криптографию, информационную безопасность (в этом я ничего посоветовать не могу) или машинное обучение (а в этом могу направить, когда появится нужда).

PS: зачем же минусовать вопрос пацану, который так стремится к знаниям? Хочет выносить себе мозг, так давайте поможем собственным большим опытом в этом нелёгком деле!